# How do you comment in the sbt repositories file?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using proxy repositories with sbt. I have many repositories to list in the repositories file so I'd like to add comments. The sbt reference manual doesn't mention the proper way to do this - https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html. Does anyone know?

Comment: Not a duplicate of that, the configuration files are different from the `.sbt` files.

Comment: This page claims to describe the format completely, but does not mention commenting. Does prefixing comments with `#` work? https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Launcher-Configuration.html

Comment: Try one of these, hope it helps: http://www.spiceforms.com/blog/list-comment-syntax-programming-languages/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that "#" is the way to go.